# Access Mac App Store via VPN

Tags: mac-appstore, vpn, proxy, geolocation

I am pretty new to Macs, but I am not sure that is relevant here. I do use a VPN sometimes (and will do so more). It seems to work OK for browsers, email etc as it should.

However, I wanted to change my location on the App Store. The reason is legitimate: A software vendor is only selling via the App Store, but is charging extra (ie ripping off) customers in my country. It is legal to get around the discriminatory pricing here with a VPN, proxy etc.

But the new "location" doesn't seem to work for the App Store, which apparently has me where I actually am, hence I have to pay the ripoff price in the local currency. Is there any way around this? Am I missing something obvious?

It is enough money to make some difference, but the principle is also important.

Comment: No need to change your location, just create new account with different country. Note that you should have a valid payment method from that country.

Answer (score 4):

The App Store does not care about your physical location, you can shop in any country's app store from any other country. To change stores, just click the flag icon at the bottom of any page.

Your main problem will be that to purchase from any country's app store, you need to use an Apple ID that has a valid billing address in that country.

Comment: You can get around the billing issue by buying foreign iTunes gift cards, and using them for payment. There are a couple of different websites that specialize in this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, on the App Store the purchase is available on the market where your Apple ID is registered. I mean, if the App Store sees that your location is US, it will switch you to the US market automatically. The only way to bypass paying extra money is to create a new Apple ID using the location where this app costs less.